# JQuery mobile popup not working when returned with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

I am having problems with Jquery mobile popup html code that has been returned by AJAX. I need this for a mobile app I am doing that calls a php page that gets text and image links from a mysql database (these will always be changing).

I have based my code on this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wbfqy/

And here is the same code not working when returned by AJAX: http://jsfiddle.net/NF2jz/4392/

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    data: {
        html: '<div data-role="content"><a href="#TEST_about" data-role="button" data-rel="popup">Popup</a><div data-role="popup" id="TEST_about" data-theme="d" ><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="d" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src="http://www.illinoisci.com/files/cellphone.gif" width="157" height="88" class="popphoto" /></div></div>'
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(msg)
    {       document.getElementById("target").innerHTML=msg;
    }              
});
```

Is there a solution to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rob I did not know about the trigger function. I got it working with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    data: {
        html: '<div data-role="content"><a href="#TEST_about" data-role="button" data-rel="popup">Popup</a><div data-role="popup" id="TEST_about" data-theme="d" ><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="d" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src="http://www.illinoisci.com/files/cellphone.gif" width="157" height="88" class="popphoto" /></div></div>'
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(msg)
    {       
     $('#target').html(msg);
     $('#target').trigger('create');
    }              
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data` key you have above is the data you are sending to the PHP script.

Therefore to insert a pop-up afterwards you would add it as below.  Notice though that you aren't sending anything specific or doing anything with the received `msg` parameter for now:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    data: {
        someParam1: 'someValue1',
        someParam2: 'someValue2',
    }
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (msg) {
        popupHTML = '<div data-role="content"><a href="#TEST_about" data-role="button" data-rel="popup">Popup</a><div data-role="popup" id="TEST_about" data-theme="d" ><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="d" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src="http://www.illinoisci.com/files/cellphone.gif" width="157" height="88" class="popphoto" /></div></div>';
        //insert the  popupHTML into the target
        $('#target').HTML(popupHTML);
        // then trigger the create event to make jQM markup the insert html properly and attach the correct events etc.
        $('#target').triggert('create');
    }
});
```

More info:

[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[jQM trigger](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/triggering-create-on-injected-content-does-not-work.html)